# Opening a .dll file with dotPeek

Tags: .net, dll, dotpeek

I have a question about .dll files.
To open .dll files i tried the programm "dotpeek".

Starting the programm, I clicked "files" browsed for my file *(it's Minesweeper.dll default windows path C:\Program Files\Microsoft Games\Minesweeper)* and i clicked "open". Everything works well, but i can't open the file! The bracket behind it, in the assembly list, says "(not supported)".
Does anybody know why?

Im not sure but i noticed that its a ".NetFramework v4.5 " and every other file in the assembly list is "v4.0" could that be the problem???

I Hope somebody can help me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

dotPeek and other similar programs like ILSpy are for .NET assemblies. Minesweeper.dll is a native DLL and thus can't be opened in dotPeek.

Comment: There is none in the way similar to dotPeek

Comment: You will get assembler or spaghetti code. You wouldn't be able to use it

Comment: something like the output of the editor? ok well i gotta reprogramm minesweeper in that case.. or find sth else thank you anyway! really apreciated :)

Comment: @tankman175: You could have just googled... [Minesweeper OpenSource](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=minesweeper%20open%20source&es_th=1)

Comment: Initially I wanted to control the in and output of a minesweeper game; I thought opening the dll would give me usefull insight but using a publicly available java version of minesweeper would definetely have been the easier solution; 
anyhow,  thanks alot for helping 16yo me ;)